# End of line after socat readbytes limit is reached

Tags: linux, socat

We wanted to use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to make a process available that is line-based:

```
socat SYSTEM:"echo \$\$;sed -u /^%/s/foo/bar/" \
  TCP-L:1234,fork,reuseaddr,readbytes=21,bind=localhost
```

This works but only until the `readbytes` limit is reached because the last "line" is cut short and the left side ("SYSTEM") does not get a newline until the next line. For example:

```
$ echo %foo | socat - tcp:localhost:1234
13047
%bar
$ echo foo w/o ^% | socat - tcp:localhost:1234
foo w/o ^%
$ echo %foo, here is a too long line | socat - tcp:localhost:1234
$ echo %foo | socat - tcp:localhost:1234
%bar, here is a too l%foo
```

The `echo \$\$` is there to demonstrate that `socat` starts the left side only once and keeps it running for multiple clients. That's what we need. But is there a way to e.g. pass a newline to the left side when the right side was cut short due to `readbytes`?

*Update 2019-03-15 00:05 UTC:*

One will probably want to add `,pty,rawer` to the left side, however, this does not help with the case where the `readbytes` limit is reached.

socat is 1.7.3.1, running on Debian 9, Linux 4.9.144.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around the issue is to count bytes and append a final newline if the limit is reached. In Bash this could be done for instance with (here including the `SYSTEM:` part from the question):

```bash
!/bin/bash
readbytes=21 # the number used in the question
echo $$
while :; do
   read -r -N 1 || break
   count=$((count+1))
   echo "byte $count is '$REPLY'" >&2
   printf '%s' "$REPLY"
   ((count<readbytes)) || { [[ $REPLY == $'\n' ]] || printf '\n'; count=0; }
   [[ $REPLY != $'\n' ]] || count=0
done \
|sed -u /^%/s/foo/bar/
```

Now, if we run `socat` using this script as in

```
socat EXEC:./script  TCP-L:1234,fork,reuseaddr,readbytes=21,bind=localhost
```

the too long line will get a newline appended, so it can be handled by `sed`:

```
$ echo %foo | socat - tcp:localhost:1234
3811702
%bar
$ echo foo w/o ^% | socat - tcp:localhost:1234
foo w/o ^%
$ echo %foo, here is a too long line | socat - tcp:localhost:1234
%bar, here is a too l
$ echo %foo | socat - tcp:localhost:1234
%bar
```